# Unexpected decimal values appearing after deducting a value from a floored number

Tags: javascript

I was trying to obtain a random number rounded off to its first decimal place.
I got what I wanted with the following code,

```
(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) / 10)
```

But when trying to deduct a value from the output, I had unexpected decimals showing up for some numbers.

```
(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) / 10) - 1 //When deducting the problem occurs.
```

Any clues as to why this is happening?

[Sample output in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satilog/kbq2snum/66/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.round`

```js
var number = document.getElementById("num");
setInterval(function() {
   number.innerHTML = Math.round(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) / 10) - 1;
 }, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="num" style="color:black">asd</p>
```